# Plotly: Hide the hoverlabel while retaining hoverData in callback

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there a way to hide the hoverlabel in a plotly figure while retaining the hoverData in a Dash callback?

I've looked everywhere, most closely related [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/hide-the-hoverlabel-while-retaining-hoverdata-and-clickdata-in-callback/43646), but nothing seems to work. The `hoverinfo` parameter isn't a valid parameter in `update_layout`, nor is `hovertemplate`. Here's my closest attempt that hides the `hoverlabel` but then unfortunately doesn't allow for the `hoverData` callback.

```
import plotly.express as px
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

ss_rgb = np.array(Image.open('test.png'))

fig = px.imshow(ss_rgb)

fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_layout(
     dragmode=False,
    hovermode=False,
    #hoverinfo='none', # invalid parameter
    #hovertemplate=False # invalid parameter
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [plotly forum post you linked](https://community.plotly.com/t/hide-the-hoverlabel-while-retaining-hoverdata-and-clickdata-in-callback/43646) has the answer. The problem with what you've tried is that `hoverinfo` and `hovertemplate` are not valid properties to set with `fig.update_layout`. They can however be set with `fig.update_traces`:

```
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='none', hovertemplate=None)
```

Complete reproducible example:

```
import json
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input


df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title="Life expectancy in Canada")

fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo="none", hovertemplate=None)

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig), html.Div(id="output")])


@app.callback(Output("output", "children"), Input("graph", "hoverData"))
def display_hover_data(hoverData):
    return json.dumps(hoverData, indent=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

[image: no-label]

Comment: *facepalm hate it when the answer is right in front of me and I don't see it haha... much thanks for catching that stupid mistake.